# ASP.NET MVC How to use User's data after they log in

Tags: forms, entity-framework, linq

If I have a form for creating a holiday request:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal" style=" position:relative; top:20px;border-radius: 0px; border-color: #F47B20; border-style: solid; border-width: 5px; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: right; padding: 60px; background-size: contain; background-color:white ">
        <h2 align="center">Holiday Request Form</h2>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeID, "Employee Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("EmployeeID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartDate,"Start Date", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate, "Start Date",new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", autocomplete = "off" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FinishDate, "Finish Date",htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FinishDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", autocomplete = "off" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FinishDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HoursTaken,"Hours Requested", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HoursTaken, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HoursTaken, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comments, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(
             model => model.Comments,
  new { placeholder = "Enter Dates and how many Hours per Date Here.", style = "width: 400px; height: 200px;" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comments, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-warning"  />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

But Instead of an Employee selecting their name of a dropdown list, The input will be based from the log in.

I already figured out how to grab the Employees Id from the log in but I am unsure how to use it in a form.

This is how I grabbed it using the controller which works for other aspects of my app

```
string name = Session["Name"].ToString();

        var EmployeeIDCatch = db.Employees.Where(s => s.Email.Equals(name)).Select(s => s.EmployeeID);
```

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.EmployeeID = new SelectList(db.Employees, "EmployeeID", "FullName");
        return View();

        string name = Session["Name"].ToString();

        var EmployeeIDCatch = db.Employees.Where(s => s.Email.Equals(name)).Select(s => s.EmployeeID);

    }

    // POST: HolidayRequestForms/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "RequestID,EmployeeID,StartDate,FinishDate,HoursTaken,Comments,YearCreated,MonthCreated,DayCreated,YearOfHoliday,Approved")] HolidayRequestForm holidayRequestForm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.HolidayRequestForms.Add(holidayRequestForm);
            db.SaveChanges();
            SendMailToAreaManager();
            SendMailToManager();
            return RedirectToAction("Index","Calendar");
        }

        ViewBag.EmployeeID = new SelectList(db.Employees, "EmployeeID", "FullName", holidayRequestForm.EmployeeID);
        return View(holidayRequestForm);
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean you are unsure on how to use it in the form? Also, instead of using EF I would suggest using Stored procedures, they're faster and more secure.

Comment: `I already figured out how to grab the Employees Id from the log in but I am unsure how to use it in a form.`-Why do you need to use in from? use it directly in controller method before inserting the data.

Comment: So Instead of a dropdown list to input the EmployeeID I want it to be autofilled based off the log in. Forgive me as I'm quite new, but what is the difference?

Comment: @Conor8630 add your post method to the question. I am giving you the solution.

Comment: @TanvirArjel Done

Comment: @Conor8630 Please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First **remove** the following code from your html form:

```
<div class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeID, "Employee Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
     <div class="col-md-10">
         @Html.DropDownList("EmployeeID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Now update your `Create` POST method as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "RequestID,StartDate,FinishDate,HoursTaken,Comments,YearCreated,MonthCreated,DayCreated,YearOfHoliday,Approved")] HolidayRequestForm holidayRequestForm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        string name = Session["Name"].ToString();

        var employeeID = db.Employees.Where(s => s.Email.Equals(name))
                           .Select(s => s.EmployeeID).FirstOrDefault();

        holidayRequestForm.EmployeeID = employeeID;

        db.HolidayRequestForms.Add(holidayRequestForm);
        db.SaveChanges();
        SendMailToAreaManager();
        SendMailToManager();
        return RedirectToAction("Index","Calendar");
    }

    return View(holidayRequestForm);
}
```

Comment: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<int>' to 'int'" get an error! will I use firstordefault?

Comment: I have updated my answer with `.Select(s => s.EmployeeID).FirstOrDefault();` Please take look again.

Comment: I just added `holidayRequestForm.EmployeeID = employeeID.FirstOrDefault();` And it Works Perfectly!! Thank you for all the help

Comment: Although its working! But it looks odd! So use my updated code instead!

Comment: Yeah sure thing.